# Retrieve new Database records

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I have been tasked with updating a MySQL database with new records on a daily basis.

The process needs to check for these new records and then append them to another database where they can be stored longer.

What would be the best method for the timing of the db call?

A Cron Job is what I am thinking but I haven't set one up before.

Any advice would be welcomed if you think this is the right method.

Thanks in advance.
Tim

Comment: What is it 'checking'?

Comment: With respect, your question is too vague to get detailed answers. Choose a time of day when your system is idle, but avoid 02:00 - 03:00 because of daylight time changeover days.  A cronjob is a good way to handle this kind of requirement. If all the work ("checking" and "appending") happens inside a single MySQL server instance, a MySQL EVENT would also work. You can look these things up on on the 'toobz.

Comment: If you are using Linux hosting then cpanel gives you option to add a cron task .you simply give the time when you want to run the script/file and just mention the code you need to run in that file